# How to update previewHtml/TextDocumentContentProvider

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing on a vscode extension. The method `provideTextDocumentContent()` returns an iframe. This works very fine, but I need to reload the iframe/website by an action of vscode. But I don't know what I have to do to update that. I would be very happy about a minimum code example :) or other help for dummies :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [webview API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview) instead. It replaces previewHtml (which is now deprecated) and should be quite a bit easier to work with

Comment: Yeah I tried once ago, it didn't work for me. I tried it again it works. Sometime programming is funny :-)